# pyqt5 comboBox - get the associate value for selected item

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

i want to set a comboBox and show my table's  `column1` data as items and associated  value `column2` is for selected item id and want to setText in a qLabel.
i am using a model to view the items in comboBox and working fine. i can get the currentText value but how to get the associated value for the items.
in my case :
my sql table like:

```
type     id
------------
DIV        2
TRANS     33
FEE       41
EXP       89
```

now , i  can set the column1(`type`) values into comboBox successfully. now, if user selected value 'FEE' , than qlable should be updated as its associate `id` : 41. how to do that!

```
df=loadData()
model=PandasModel(df)

self.comboBox.setModel(model)
self.comboBox.setModelColumn(0) 

content=self.comboBox.currentText()
self.label.setText(content) # content should be ID instead of currentText
```

pandasMode:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]+1
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._df.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None
        
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
       
      
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role != QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._df.values):
            return False
        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= self._df.columns.size:
            return False
        self._df.values[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True
    
    # def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
    #     return len(self._df.index)
    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._df.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): 
        return len(self._df.columns)

    def sort(self, column, order):
        colname = self._df.columns.tolist()[column]
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._df.sort_values(colname, ascending= order == QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder, inplace=True)
        self._df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc i have edited my question, i am using 'pandasModel' to get datas

Comment: Note: for the following occasions you must add the classes or functions that do not belong to the PyQt library since the model you provide is not standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the model stores the id in the second column then it has to obtain the associated index:

```py
ID_COLUMN = 1
index = self.comboBox.model().index(
    self.comboBox.currentIndex(), ID_COLUMN, self.comboBox.rootModelIndex()
)
id_ = index.data()
print(id_)
self.label.setText(id_)
```